# Vue 3 - The official way to update shallowReactive array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I have for example the following array:

```js
setup() {
   let array = shallowReactive([]);
   return {
      array
   };
}
```

Using of shallow reactive is important, because this array could contains not reactive objects, that in turn can have reactive fields itself. I need to filter its elements. The following code doesn't work because it creates a new object, that has no common with `array` that used in the template:

```js
array = array.filter(obj => !obj.empty)
```

The only known to me way that preserves reactivity is:

```js
array.splice(0, array.length, ...array.filter(obj => !obj.empty))
```

But it looks ugly and possibly is not effective. Are there any other ways that preserves reactivity?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the content of the array, using splice is the cleanest way. (as opposed to push, shift etc.).

It's common to use a computed to have a copy of your array that will have the filtered copy of the array, but that might not be what you're looking for.

Another option is to use a `ref` or `shallowRef` instead of the `shallowReactive`

Unfortunately, AFAIK, there's no way to change the target of the Proxy externally that `shallowReactive` creates.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you?

```
import { ref, computed } from "vue"
```

```js
setup() {
   const shallowReactive = ref([{obj:'1'}, {obj:'2'}, {}])
   const array = computed( () =>  shallowReactive.value.filter(obj => obj.obj))
   console.log(array.value)

   return {
      array
   };
}
```

Comment: I need to change the `array`, it may be filtering, sorting or etc.